# Postfix generic rewrites receipent addres

Tags: email, postfix-mta

How to prevent generic maps to rewrite receipent address? My generic looks like:

name1@domain.com    devs@domain.com
name2@domain.com    devs@domain.com

If I send mail from name1@domain.com to name3@domain.com generic rewrite from field and put devs@domain.com as a sender. It is completely OK. But if I send mail from name1@domain.com to name2@domain.com, message with devs@domain.com is sent to devs@domain.com (recipient is overwrited also). Can I prevent this?

main.cf row:
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this. Instead of generic maps, I put into main.cf next lines:

```
sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender  
sender_canonical_maps =  regexp:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical_maps  
smtp_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_check
```

In file /etc/postfix/sender_canonical_maps:

```
/.+/    devs@domain.com
```

And in file /etc/postfix/header_check:

```
enter code here
/From:.*/ REPLACE From: devs@domain.com
```

After that, execute:

```
enter code here
/etc/postfix/#postmap sender_canonical_maps  
/etc/postfix/#postmap header_check
```

And restart postfix, and voila!